# Check if user already exists Firebase swift 3.0

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, eula

```
let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    database.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let ui = value["id"] as! String
            if ui != FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
            {
                var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                if s == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if p == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "big", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if se == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "se", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if os == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "4s", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if ip1 == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ipad1", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if ipb == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ipadbig", bundle: nil)
                }

                        let naviVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eula")as! UIViewController
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = naviVC

            }
            else
            {
                var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                if s == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if p == true{
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "big", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if se == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "se", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if os == true{
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "4s", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if ip1 == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ipad1", bundle: nil)
                }
                else if ipb == true
                {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ipadbig", bundle: nil)
                }
                let naviVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yo")as! UIViewController
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = naviVC
            }
        }


    })
```

I have a firebase app, and I want to check if a user exists in my databse, If the don't i want to display a licenses agreement, but if they do i don't have too. My current method only works if there are two users. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

```
  let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    database.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)

        if snapshot.hasChild( FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change .ChildAdded to .value. This will make sure its reading the data when you start.

Answer (score 0):

With that code I think it will only execute when a child is added. I can't check it out right now but try with

```
database.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.Value, with:{ (snapshot) in
            ...
    })
```

As I said I can't check it so answer me if you have any problem. Good luck!

Comment: @AtaerCaner  .Value crashed my app

Comment: Yeah  I didn't remember it well but it had to be with .Value in your case.

Comment: Ya I realized it had to be .value right after I posted

Comment: It is also a lowercase v now

Comment: And also you don't need FIRDataEventType, you could use: observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in